# How to check if my OpenSSL supports ALPN?

Tags: centos, openssl, alpn

I search if my server is running OpenSSL with ALPN support. I need that to know if I have to install OpenSSL again but with ALPN support or I can skip that. I want to build HTTP/2 at DirectAdmin server. 
I've used `openssl version -a | grep -i alpn` but nothing showed up.

My system:

```
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
```

OpenSSL:

```
OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
built on: Mon Feb 20 14:38:48 UTC 2017
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need OpenSSL 1.0.2 for ALPN support. You would already have this if you had updated your system. You should do that now.